# Import existing project to heroku

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, heroku

I have an existing Spring MVC project. I want to upload this to [heroku](http://java.heroku.com/) **but I don't know how.**

I installed heroku following [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse). Can anyone please point me in right direction, for **how can I import my existing Spring MVC project to heroku**

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @UVM I don't know where to start. I have this project on my eclipse. But I don't know how to upload it to the heroku.

Comment: Once you upload the application to Heroku, you need to verify by logging into it.It is mentioned in Heroku web site how to do it.Please go through their tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to do a similar thing at the moment, but I am deploying my application to CloudBees. [This](http://osintegrators.com/node/145) article explains how to deploy a Spring MVC application to a number of PaaS hosting providers (CloudBees, CloudFoundry, Heroku, Windows Azure, OpenShift, Elastic Beanstalk and Google AppEngine). It was of some help to me. Maybe it will be useful to you too. You could also have a look at [this](http://www.infoworld.com/d/cloud-computing/which-freaking-paas-should-i-use-204189) article which compares all these services.

If you decide to go with CloudBees, note that they will host your application on Tomcat 6 by default. If you need another server (Tomcat 7, JBoss, GlassFish, etc.) you can switch it easily, but you need to download their SDK
and deploy your application with the `bees app:deploy` command-line tool which is a part of the SDK.

They have simple and detailed [instructions](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/GettingStarted) on deployment, DB configuration etc.

**UPDATE:**

This answer is not relevant any longer, as CloudBees are going to stop providing application hosting services (both free and paid). I received an email from them which says that they discontinue free accounts on 24 September 2014.

Comment: I looked into the CloudBees, but there is this file the `persistence.xml`, I'm not using hybernate do I have to add this file?

Comment: @user2785929 My application does not used DB at all at the moment. So I only had to go through steps 1-6 in the CloudBees section. If you do not use Hibernate you will not need `persistence.xml`.

Comment: 1 last question how do I upload an existing database to this?

Comment: I have never done it yet. There is more information available on their web site once you register. And their user interface is simple enough so you may not need any documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the site. I will go with CloudBees, it is more easy to deploy there.

Comment: Alexey sorry for bothering you, but did you successfully uploaded your web app with database?

Comment: @user2785929 I do not need a DB for now. The app is running.